# Update a Column with Date Format (01- Jan-2014)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Emp that has the Date column. All the dates in the column are in the format

01/05/2014

I want to Convert all the dates in this column to the format 05-JAN-2014

How do I Alter the whole columns once I have already got data in it?

I was trying to do some thing like this

```
UPDATE Emp SET HireDate = replace(convert(char(15),HireDate ,106),' ',' - ')
```

This does not Alter my column.

here Emp  =  Table 
     HireDate =  Column I need to convert.

Comment: What data type has that column?

Comment: Please, please store the data as a `datetime` and format it when you're going to display it somewhere.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to store dates as a `Char`... Why?  Use `Date` or `DateTime` to store dates.

Comment: The Column in in VarChar format.

Comment: @user3614477 don't. Just don't. Do what they said. Change it to `DATETIME`. Just don't do this. No matter what you do. Don't do this.

Comment: If you change it to a character format (especially one as horrendous as VMS format), then sorts and comparisons on that column will **not** do what you expect.  For example, 05-JAN-2014 will occur *after* 05-FEB-2014 in a sorted sequence.  If you must have characters, then at least use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format:  2014-01-05

Comment: Not to mention, you'll be storing fifteen character bytes (encoding permitting) where eight numeric ones will perfectly suffice. You're losing a huge part of functionality in exchange for wasting seven bytes on each and every row.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
UPDATE Emp SET HireDate = REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(15), CONVERT(DATETIME, HireDate), 106), ' ', '-')
```

But as was said in the comments, just don't do this. Store your dates as dates, then handle formatting on the client-side, when you're printing it out. This is a waste of space, and just bad practice. You might be saying to yourself, "wow, Matthew, that sure doesn't look like a very nice way of doing this." That's because it isn't a nice thing to do. There is *no* nice way of doing this.